# How to use sessions with Spring Data REST?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

Normally, we use the annotation `@SessionAttributes("myAttribute")` over the `@Controller` class, to enable sessions. But if we're using Spring Data REST, i.e. exposing our repository directly using `@RepositoryRestResource`, then we don't have to make a separate class for the controller.
Then, in this case where do I use the annotation `@SessionAttributes("myAttribute")` or how do I use sessions? Could someone explain with an example?

Comment: Generally, with a REST API, you let the client remember state. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I just want to emulate the use of `@SessionAttributes` on `@RepositoryRestResource`, since I don't have an explicit controller to annotate

Comment: Yes, but why? Why maintain state on the server?

Comment: I'm not really writing an application, so I don't have an answer to that. But I have to teach this module in class (as a self-learning assignment), and was just wondering if it's possible.
Thanks for all your help so far

Comment: Long story short, you won't use @SessionAttributes with rest resources.